# How do you update/change a product's store/website via Magento's CSV importer?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, import

Using Magento 1.9.2.

I'd like to be able to re-assign products between stores by uploading a CSV containing product SKUs and store names or IDs.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is possible by using Magento's Import/Export Profiles feature (found via the System menu at the top).

Format a CSV file like this:

```
sku,websites
BANANA69,"1,8"
```

This will replace, not update, the stores so you can remove products from stores by simply not listing that store ID.

Use the numeric store ID which can be found on the Stores settings page.

The correct header name was listed in [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80481/import-bulk-products-with-mixed-categories-types-multiselect-attributes) so thanks to that author too.